# PHP regex to hyphenate URLs but ignore curly apostrophes

Tags: php, regex, drupal-7

I recently migrated a website to Drupal. Some of the old page titles contain curly apostrophes in words like `what's`.

In conducting this migration we changed a lot of URLs to simplify the site layout and make the URLs more intuitive.

I am trying to set up a forwarding system that captures requests for the old URL and then redirects users to the new URL, which is based on the new page's title.

This works very nicely except for the pages that contain curly apostrophes in their titles, because Drupal encodes these curlies in the urls it has created, but my forwarder removes them, and I need to stop it doing so!

At present I clean up the page title using this expression:

`/[^a-z\-\d]+/i` (with a preg_replace)

...to substitute a hyphen (`-`) in place of any non-standard characters and spaces.

I realise that curly apostrophes are encoded differently and hence are being trapped and removed by this expression.

How do I inform my regex to ignore curly apostrophes and not turn them into a hyphen?

Comment: how many different types of apostrophes are there? if there is only one, why don't you simply replace them with a str_replace("'", "", $value)?

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. The problem is that I need to preserve them rather than remove them, because all of the URLs generated by Drupal during the migration process contain them! So I want to keep the curlies in whereas at the moment I am removing them and I cannot find a way to do this.

Comment: ok chris, and what about [^a-z-\d'] ? by the way, you could simply remove the apostrophes in the database-query with REPLACE()

Comment: Cheers; I considered that, but then the problem becomes that it limits things in future, extending the legacy of the bad past! I wanted a simple-self-contained solution to the old problem... I did try your suggestion when I researched the problem before posing this question, but it didn't work. I am wondering if the database encoding is the problem. I don't think it's UTF-8, but I'm not expert enough to understand the implications of that, or how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might find using [filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) usefull.

```
$var="http://www.w3s'choo��ls.co�m";

var_dump(filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

The `$var` will keep the " ' " character, but sanitize invalid ones.